# JSPDF Auto Table Custom Styles From Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a table like below

```html
<table id="tbl">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="left-align">Name</th>
        <td class="right-align bold">Amount</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And i use jspdf like below code

```
doc.autoTable({
    startY:30,
    html: '#tbl',
});
```

I want to format rows according to class and make them bold and aligned by their class when save the JSPDF output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667405/jspdf-autotable-target-style-for-specific-row-of-a-table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useCss` option to parse some simply css styles such as font style and text alignment.